# Select rows with matching columns in other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables and I want to query them and get results based on 
Table 1 Team ID .

I think its simple but I failed to work this out.

All I'm trying to do is get their select their data from other tables and group them by TeamID.

The structure of tables is as follows:

Table 1 
This table holds the teams entries by PersonID - referenced by PersonID Table, Each team is in one row

```
[TeamID]  Tournament_id  Person_1_ID   Person_2_ID     Person_3_ID     Country_ID
  ---     ---------      --------        ----------    ---------       --------
  1          77789          123           124              125           90
  2          77789          126           127              128           95
  3          77789          129           130              131            5
        .........
```

Table 2 
This is the person table PersonID = Primary Key

```
 [PersonID]     Name         Dob             Email           Country_ID
  ---------    -------     --------        ----------        ------------
    123        John      19/03/1992      John@live.com          90
    124        Moe       20/10/1995      Moe@live.com           90
    125        Sami      10/05/1989      Sami@example.com       90
    126        Kim       30/01/1990      Kim@company.com        95
.......
```

Table 3
Participation table

```
[ParticipationID]     PersonID      tournament_id          Country_id
 -----------------   ----------     -------------         ------------- 
     9999901            123             77789                  90
     9999902            124             77789                  90
     9999903            125             77789                  90
     9999904            126             77789                  95
     9999905            127             77789                  95 
.......................
```

How do I get this output

```
TeamID     Tournament_Id     Name     Country_ID 
------      -----------     -----     ------    
  1          777789         John         90 
  1          777789         Moe          90
  1          777789         Sami         90 
  2          777789         Kim          95
```

Comment: "Each team is in one row" That was your first mistake

Comment: @Strawberry Well, it is a mistake I admit it, do you have any suggestion? like re-structuring the Team table?

Comment: Exactly. As a minimum, you would typically have a table of teams and a table of players. The `players` table would record the details of the player, and the team to which they belong.

Comment: @Strawberry The person table is the players table which stores the details of players, the team table is for holding teams which they belong to. so for example if I re-structure the team table what is the key to match both of these tables?

Comment: team(team_id*,team_name),person(person_id*,dob,team_id)

Comment: Country_ID isn't enough as team id in the person table? :/

Comment: I don't know. If a country has exactly one team, and each team represents exactly one country, then either team_id or country_id is redundant. In general, a foreign key in one table references (a component of) a primary key in another table,

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT t.TeamID
       ,t.Tournament_Id
       ,pr.Name
       ,pr.Country_Id
FROM Team AS t
INNER JOIN Participation AS p ON p.tournament_id = t.Tournament_id
INNER JOIN Person AS pr ON pr.PersonID = p.PersonID
WHERE Tournament_Id = 777789
```